# Help me understand why find returns something different than end() on std::set when set is empty

Tags: c++, boost, std

why is the if-case true?!

```
 typedef std::set< boost::shared_ptr<CCall>, HasFirstQueuedLongerTime> queued_container;
    queued_container::iterator itTemp = queued.find(spCall);
    queued_container::iterator itTempEnd = queued.end();
    if(itTemp != itTempEnd ) //<-- is true
```

`queued` is an empty `std::set` and `spCall` is a shared pointer to an object. Since `queued`is empty the find function should return the iterator equal to `queued.end()`...

Im compiling and debugging on vs2005. I can see that `itTemp` and `itTempEnd` points to same address.

Thankful for all answers!

More code info, the following is declared before if-statement:

```
queued_container queuedCalls;
const boost::shared_ptr<CCall> &spCall; //spCall is valid according to debug info.


struct HasFirstQueuedLongerTime : std::binary_function < boost::shared_ptr<CCall>, boost::shared_ptr<CCall>, bool> {
        bool operator() (const boost::shared_ptr<CCall>& lhs, const boost::shared_ptr<CCall>& rhs) const
        {
            return lhs->CreatedTime() < rhs->CreatedTime(); //returns true if lhs queued longer time than rhs
        }
    };
```

My real executable code:

```
queued_container::iterator itTemp = queued.find(spCall);
queued_container::iterator itTempEnd = queued.end();

if(itTemp != itTempEnd )
    AS_ERROR(1, "XXX", "ERROR: Already added to queue container.");
queued.insert(spCall);
CCallQueue::insert(spCall);
```

Ps. Sorry for many edits..

Comment: Title is quite ambiguous. I'd expect `find` to fail in empty sets. But that's "fail" as in "returns iterator to end of collection"

Comment: @user521048: Produce a real self contained testcase. The above does not give enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Please tell me what would be interesting to know regarding this.

Comment: Most likely the comparator (HasFirstQueuedLongerTime) is inconsistent.

Comment: As @wilx - executable code that shows the issue

Comment: Are you sure `queued` is empty? Did you really check it? It is not obvious from your code snippet.

Comment: -1 The additional code you've posted is not even valid. Please post a **complete, minimal example** exhibiting the problem. We are not telepaths.

Comment: -1 Even with numerous edits this question still has many unanswered questions.  You can make this a good question by posting a runnable example, complete with `main()`, that replicates the problem.

Comment: What is your container's real name? Is it `queued` or `queuedCalls`? Could the problem simply be that you've confused the two names in your code?

Comment: @Alf: you're not a telepath? I'm disappointed ..

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

```
itTemp != itTempEnd
```

was never true! The function below AS_ERROR was a "#define-function" with multiple statements. So the first statement was never executed but the second was.

Comment: That's why you must not use defines where you can do it better with a function.